# on clicking any pencil icons to update the record, the currency data fields that are in SEK change to SGD

Tags: lightning-experience, page-layout, currency, edit

on clicking any pencil icons to update the record, the  currency data fields that are in SEK change to SGD (User's local currency). On saving the records the currency changes back to SEK.
This should not be happen. Edit layout should also show the same currency as on detail layout.

[image: Detail Page]

[image]

Comment: Hi Vicky. Please could you update the question to add some screenshots to help us understand exactly what happens? This would, for example, indicate whether currency conversions also occur, What the currency field for the object states and what type of object you are editing.

Comment: Hi, I have added the screenshots. Detail page and the edit page.

Comment: Great. Can you confirm the type of object? (One of the standard types or a custom one?) And if you set an exchange rate, do you see value conversion happen?

Comment: It is the custom Object. Value conversion happens in trigger. But on UI i can see same values for both the currency. Anyhow that same currency should be displayed  on edit field also

Comment: Do you have a field that identifies the currency for your custom object?

Comment: Yes we have the currency field in object from which we are showing and converting the cost value.